# Why does $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2 \sec^2x \tan x}{\sin x } = 2$

Tags: real-analysis

I am taking intro the Analysis, and in the text book we have a simple example, which has this as a conclusion:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2 \sec^2x \tan x}{\sin x } = 2$$

I feel a bit ashamed as this is just calculus, but $\tan 0 = 0$ and $\sin 0 = 0$ so it seems that this claim cannot be true, and we should apply L'Hôpital's Rule. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that by [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) the $\sin x$ factors cancel out

$$\frac{2 \sec^2x \tan x}{\sin x }=\frac{2 \frac1{\cos^2x} \frac{\color{red}{\sin x}}{\cos x}}{\color{red}{\sin x }}=\frac{2  }{\cos^3 x }\to 2$$

Comment: seems weird that math works like this sometimes, equivalent expressions evaluate to different answers.

Comment: The point is that we have eliminated the $\sin x$ factor which lead to an indeterminate form.